Can I pass authority for a subdomain to a private AWS Route53 zone?
I have some subdomains that I want to pass management off to for development purposes. By policy we are only allowed to use AWS Route53 private zones. I'd prefer not to configure each workstation working with access to that VPC to have to manage their DNS servers as many of them are mobile and connectivity to the DNS servers are not always going to work. I imagine I could have the public DNS servers for our domain pass authority for private zone and these would only work for workstations with appropriate connectivity. My expectation is that when the private zone is inaccessible, it'll just not be able to resolve and that's acceptable.
What do I need to do to pass authority to an AWS private zone?

Create a NS record in the parent zone that delegates authority.
Make sure your resolvers have access to the private zone, if Route53 has such restrictions. Workstations don't chase delegations; they rely on their configured DNS server to handle it.
So if the authoritative server is made to be only accessible within the VPC, then a workstation that uses (e.g.) your home WiFi router as its DNS server will not be able to resolve those names – even if it is connected to the same VPC.
